# How to integrate thinkific in my react native application

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile

I have a client who owns a thinkific portal like he has courses and and all stuff there on his thinkific site.
He wants an app to be made to show the lecture videos on his app.
I checked out the public API provided by thinkific but couldn't find how to implement login in my app using the same thinkific backend.
The main problem is i want to give login option to users to sign into the app using thinkific credentials and then they have all the lecture videos.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.
For those who dont know what is thinkific you can google it.